# Understanding Arnold's definition of "differentiable"

Tags: calculus-of-variations, variational-analysis

I'm looking at Arnold's [*Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics*](https://books.google.com/books?id=5OQlBQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=mathematical+methods+of+classical+mechanics&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwje9vTywr3cAhWwmOAKHeyQB4QQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=mathematical%20methods%20of%20classical%20mechanics&f=false) at the beginning of chapter 3 p 55 which defines when a functional is differentiable.  Slightly paraphrasing and skipping a couple of details:

> A functional $\Phi$ is said to be differentiable if
>   $\Phi(\gamma+h)-\Phi(\gamma)=F+R$
>
> where $F(\gamma,h)$ is linear in $h$ and $R\sim O(h^2)$ in the sense that 
>   for $|h|<\epsilon$ and $\left|\frac{dh}{dt}\right|<\epsilon$ then $|R|<C\epsilon^2$.

I've been telling myself to think of $\gamma$ as a curve, $h$ as a slight variation of the curve, and $F$ as the differential or "principal variation" of the functional, and $R$ the "error."

This is my first time seeing this definition of "differentiable" and also of $O(h^2)$, and I have a pair of questions about the latter.

1. In the 50 pages preceding, I can't seem to find out what $|\cdot |$ means here. Is $|h|$ total variation of the curve $h$, or something like that?
2. How can I make sense of the constraints $|h|<\epsilon$ and $\left|\frac{dh}{dt}\right|<\epsilon$ controlling $R$?  The best I've come up with is "if $h$ does not go up and down too much and the speed doesn't go up and down too much, then $R$ will be under control." It might be helpful to have a prototypical example of a situation where $h$ slow but too wavy, and a situation where $h$ is not wavy but the speed varies wildly. Good heuristics are welcome too.

Comment: $|h|$ is $\|h\|_{\infty}$ on $[t_0,t_1]$ for the next theorem. The definition is left ambiguous to adjust it to each case. see, for example, footnote 26. Think of it as a template of many definitions, parametrized by the spaces of curves chosen, the norms chosen, etc.

Comment: @HGLandcaster ....each case? well... I would think it is quite unusual if the definition of $O(h^2)$ is variable based on the problem presented.  Are you sure it's not just the sup norm everywhere?

Comment: It might be enough for all what follows, I didn't continue reading much more.

Comment: It is not unusual for $O(h^2)$ and differentials to [depend on the norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative). It just happens that in finite dimensions they are equivalent.

Comment: @HGLandcaster ok, a bit of a surprise, but good to know. Thanks!

Comment: @HGLandcaster is the first paragraph after the yellow box a reasonable interpretation?

Comment: That is what the definition is saying, compare to the definition of Frechet derivative, in the link, or to the [definition of differential in finite dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_in_higher_dimensions).

Comment: @HGLandcaster Ah, seeing it rewritten this way helps me see the connection better. Thank you

Comment: @HGLandcaster I still feel like there is a disconnect with the version where the difference quotient goes to $0$ and the version above where things are explained in terms of $|h|$ and $|dh/dt|$ constraining $|R|$.  If you can explain this, that would be a helpful solution.

Comment: @HGLandcaster This is where I'm running ashore:  given the condition on $|h|<\epsilon$ and $|R|<\epsilon^2$, $|\Phi(\gamma+h)-\Phi(\gamma)-F(\gamma)|/|h|<\epsilon$. Then since this is true for any $\epsilon$ and $h$'s satisfying $|h|<\epsilon$, the limit as $|h|$ goes to zero is $0$. But where does $|dh/dt|$ come in?!

Comment: In the same way that you can put $\|h\|_{0,\infty}=\sup_{x\in[a,b]}|h(x)|$, in spaces in which you have more derivatives [you can have as norm $\|h\|_{1,\infty}=\|h\|_{0,\infty}+\|h'\|_{0,\infty}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#Sobolev_spaces_with_integer_k). So, it is just a choice of space, a choice of norm.

Comment: @HGLandcaster I don't think I'm talking about norms anymore...

Comment: It would be the norm $\|\cdot\|_{1,\infty}$ using the notation of the link. It controls both the function and its derivative.

Comment: @HGLandcaster Oh, hang on, I've been a little dense in the past few comments... So the particular norm actually depends on $h$ *and its derivative*?  That's interesting... but can you see what I'm saying above? the difference quotient appears to have nothing to do with $|dh|/|dt|$... how does it use that information?

Comment: Arnold didn't write a difference quotient, and I linked to a definition with an explicit difference quotient, but in the denominator it has a norm of $h$, $\|h\|_V$, not made explicit, which I didn't imply it to be the $|\cdot|$ from Arnold. In these last few comments what I am saying is that the definition of Frechet derivative would correspond to Arnold's definition using the $\|h\|_{1,\infty}$. Arnold doesn't seem to say what his $|\cdot|$ is, but it looks like it should, or it could be $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$.

Comment: @HGLandcaster I know Arnold didn't write the difference quotient, but I wonder if his definition can be expressed equivalently by a difference quotient or not. I feel like it's at the core of my puzzlement.  I'm trying to figure out why it looks like this instead of what's at your link, and how to reconcile both views.

Comment: It is equivalent. Assuming that Arnold's $|\cdot|$ is $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}=\|\cdot\|_{0,\infty}$, use $\frac{\|\Phi(\gamma+h)-\Phi(\gamma)-F(\gamma)\|_{\infty}}{\|h\|_{1,\infty}}$

Comment: @HGLandcaster OK:  I'll take that and think about it a little more. Thanks.

Comment: @HGLandcaster would you consider writing a solution? It would help resolve the status of this question